# how to get a specific tag from a html received in json

Tags: javascript, html, shopify-api

I get the html sections from another page with `Section Rendering API`. And that works fine:

```
function handleResponse() {
   JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText)['sections_id']);
}  
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('load', handleResponse);
request.open('GET', '/?sections=sections_id', true);
request.send();
```

Also, I insert this received html into the tag with the selector:

```
document.querySelector('selector').innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText)['sections_id']
```

`['sections_id']` - this is key

And that works well, too, but I have a question. For example, the structure of this received html is like this:

```
<div class='main'>
   <div class='item'>text</div>
   <div class='item'>text</div>
   <div class='item'>text</div>
   <img src='img.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>
```

But how do I get all the divisions with selector `item`, and also the `img` tag? Or get a specific selector? Thank you.

Comment: select all divisions using js?

Comment: @AliMohammedManzoor, yes, I want to select all `item` by counting the number through the for{} loop or forEch of these tags, and also, I would like to extract a specific selector from this html.

Comment: you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.item')`. This will give you a list of divisions with class name item. You can use for loop and access their properties

Comment: @AliMohammedManzoor, I tried this before, but it didn't help

Comment: have you created the div using json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) for this.

```js
let responseHTML = `<div class='main'>
   <div class='item'>text item 1</div>
   <div class='item'>text item 2</div>
   <div class='item'>text item 3</div>
   <img src='img.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>`;

const DOM = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(responseHTML, 'text/html');

const items = DOM.querySelectorAll('.item, img');

document.body.append(...items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');

for(let i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
  console.log(main[i]);
  for (const child of main[i].children) {
    console.log(child.innerText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to calculate the number of selectors. But I can't get html from json as **html**

Comment: if you get data in json and have to put it as html you need to create the elements dynamically like, var div = document.createElement('div'); and you set class main on that and add the childs ... and then you append everything into the document.

Comment: maybe i missunderstand... can you post the json you working with?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did - **need to create the elements dynamically**

Comment: Good, I see you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a crutch way by creating a temporary `div` as a repository, allowing me to extract the html from it.
But if anyone has a better solution, I'd love to see it.

The request has been changed to `fetch`.

```
fetch("?sections=sections_id").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    let section_text = data['sections_id'];
    let section_html = document.createElement("div");
    section_html.innerHTML = section_text;
    console.log(section_html.querySelector('any_selector'));                                                                                           
});
```